# Why does $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2 = An^3+Bn^2+Cn + D$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I've got this question because of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7iKLZQ-vCk) (around 3:15). I wonder how setting up a system of $3$ equations will help him solve this problem. I'm thinking I might not understand this because I've never really used a system of equations before to solve real life problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another way you might gain an intuition for why such a form works.

So you want a closed form for the sum $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i = 1} i^2$

First consider all numbers of the form $\displaystyle k^3 - (k - 1)^3$, and sum this series from $1$ to $n$, which gives us  $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{1} k^3 - (k - 1)^3$. Now notice that all the entries of this series cancels out except for the $n^3$ and $0^3$ terms, but since $0^3 = 0$, we have that $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{1} k^3 - (k - 1)^3 = n^3$ (If you want to see this clearly, just write out the whole sum and then see the cancellation occuring!)

But, via simple algebraic manipulation $\displaystyle k^3 - (k - 1)^3 = k^3 - (k^3 - 3k^2 + 3k - 1) = 3k^2 - 3k + 1$.

So, $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{1} k^3 - (k - 1)^3 = n^3 = \sum^{n}_{1}(3k^2 - 3k + 1) = \sum^{n}_{1}3k^2 - \sum^{n}_{1}3k + \sum^{n}_{1} 1$.

So we have that $\displaystyle n^3 = \sum^{n}_{1}3k^2 - \sum^{n}_{1}3k + \sum^{n}_{1} 1 \Rightarrow n^3 + \sum^{n}_{1}3k - \sum^{n}_{1} 1 = 3\sum^{n}_{1}k^2$.

Now, you should remind yourself (or prove via a very similar method to what I have used so far) that $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{1}k = \dfrac{n(n + 1)}{2}$, and that $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{1} 1$ is simply $n$ (which is easy enough to see since you're summing $n$ $1$s).

So the maximum degree of the polynomial $\displaystyle n^3 + \sum^{n}_{1}3k - \sum^{n}_{1} 1 $ can only be $3$ at most since all other terms have degree less than $3$. This means the closed form for $\displaystyle 3\sum^{n}_{1}k^2$ is also a polynomial (of $n$) of degree 3 at most, and since that $3$ in front of the sum is just a constant, you can divide it out.

So $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{1}k^2 = An^3 + Bn^2 + Cn + D$

You can extend this method to find the closed sum of the sum of series of any powers, and infact, via induction, you can show that $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i = 1} i^k = An^{k + 1} + Bn^{k} + Cn^{k - 1} + ...$.

Comment: I wonder how $k^3 - (k - 1)^3$ relates to the form $i^2$ in terms of the polynomial degree. Thanks for being patient BTW, I'm not that experienced yet.

Comment: The sum for $k^3 - (k - 1)^3$ gives you $n^3$. Now by algebraic manipulation I showed that $k^3 - (k - 1)^3 = 3k^2 - 3k + 1$. Clearly, if you sum one side of the equals sign, then you must sum the other side. The left hand side reduces to $n^3$ as we know, and the right hand side sums to something. But we know the sum for $k$ from $1$ to $n$, which is the formula for the triangular numbers, and the sum for $1$ from $1$ to $n$, which is the $1 + 1 + ... + 1$ n times, which equals $n$. So we rearrange to get a polynomial in terms of the $k^2$ part.

Comment: Now, since the sum for the triangular numbers, is at most degree 2, and the $1 + 1 + ... + 1 = n$, is of degree 1 in terms of $n$, the maximum degree is 3, for $n^3$ because we rearranged. Now this means the closed form for $k^2$ must also be a polynomial of degree 3 max since the other side of the equals side is degree 3 as well.

Comment: Apologies if this still doesn't make sense, I kind of rushed. And also sorry for so many commas, when I rush I comma splice everything apparently. Also don't worry about asking questions :)

Comment: I'm a bit slow as you can tell haha, but I understand that you went all the way from $k^3-(k-1)^3$ to $3\sum^{n}_{1}k^2$ to prove to me that the form $k^2$ will always have a degree less or equal to 3. One thing that blows my mind is, how you discovered all this. How did you know that starting with $k^3-(k-1)^3$ would help you figure this out?

Comment: Does every sigma equation have a closed finite polynomial form?

Comment: I didn't discover it myself but read it in a book a while ago. But it's definitely an awesome technique. Remember, that sigma is just a notation for sum, so there's no such thing as a "sigma" equation, but every series of the form $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i = 1}i^k$ does have a closed polynomial form like I mentioned at the bottom of my original post. But if you're asking if any series $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i = 1} a_i$ has a closed form, where $(a_i)$ is any sequence, then the answer is usually no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20344/discussion-between-ejcqw-and-user1534664).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this the following way:

Show first that $k^2 = A\left(k^3-(k-1)^3 \right)+B\left(k^2-(k-1)^ 2\right)+C\left(k-(k-1) \right)$.

Then sum from $k=1$ to $k=n$ and use the fact that the RHS is telescopic.

This shows in general that 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^k = An^{k+1}+Bn^k+Cn^{k-1} + ...$$

If you know that this formula holds, you can find $A,B,C,...$ by finding them in the first equation.

Aternately, writing the equations for $n=1, n=2, n=3, ... ,n=k+1$ you get a system.

**Added**: **if you know linear algebra:** The polynomials $X^3-(X-1)^3 \,;\, X^2-(X-1)^2\,;\, X-(X-1)$ have pairwise distinct degrees, thus they are linearly independent. Therefore, they are a basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most two. Hence $X^2$ can be written as a linear combination of these polynomials.

**If you don't know linear algebra**

Note that by opening the brackets we have
$$A(k^3-(k-1)^3)+B(k^2-(k-1)^2)+C(k-(k-1))= A( 3k^2-3k+1)+B(2k-1)+C \\
=k^2 ( 3A )+ k(-3A +2B)+(A-B+C)$$

Since we want to get exactly $k^2$ we want
$$3A=1 \\
2B=3A=1 \\
C=B-A \,.$$

This shows that, unless I made a mistake by typing too fast, that $A=\frac{1}{3}, B=\frac{1}{2}, C=\frac{1}{6}$.

We proved that they exists by finding them.

Comment: What does it mean for a side to be telescopic?

Comment: @user1534664 When you sum the right side from $1$ to $k$, you get $k^3 - (k-1)^3 + (k-1)^3 - (k-2)^3 + \dots + 2^3 - 1^3 + 1^3 - 0^3$, and similar for the other terms. This cancellation of the intermediate terms is called telescoping.

Comment: Also, a faster and more numerically stable approach is to use Newton interpolation, rather than working in the "standard form" above. On a computer, the speed doesn't really matter until $k$ is rather large, but the numerical stability becomes a problem even when $k$ is as small as $10$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. I've only got into sequences and series two days ago, so I don't know what Newton interpolation means. I'll look into that soon.

Comment: @user1534664 The Newton interpolation comment was more directed at N.S.; it's not necessary in this case where $k$ is not too large. The idea of Newton interpolation is not hard, though: instead of writing the system in the form above, you write it as $a_0 + a_1 n + a_2 n (n-1) + a_3 n (n-1) (n-2) + \dots$, where the $a$'s are unknown constants. This makes the system much easier to deal with. The result can be expanded into your form, if desired.

Comment: Why does $k^2 = A(k^3-(k-1)^3) + B(K^2-(k-1)^2)+C(k-(k-1))$? That's the part I don't understand. I think I'll ask this to my math teacher next week. It's kind of hard for me to grasp this.

Comment: @user1534664 I will add the explanation.

Comment: @user1534664 A sketch: In the first term, the $k^3$ terms cancel each other, but a $k^2$,$k$, and constant term stick around. In the second term, the $k^2$ terms cancel each other, but a $k$ and a constant term stick around. In the last term a constant term sticks around. You can choose $A$ to get the right coefficient (namely $1$) on $k^2$; then you can choose $B$ to cancel out the extra $k$ term; then you can choose $C$ to cancel out the extra constant term. I'm sure N.S. will explain it more clearly :)

Comment: @user1534664 Done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta$ the backward difference operator:
$$\delta p(x)=p(x)-p(x-1).$$
If $p$ is a polynomial with degree $n$, then $\delta p$ is a polynomial with degree $n-1$.

Since $\delta$ is invertible, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}n^k $$
is a polynomial in $N$ with degree $k+1$. In our case,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} n^2 = A N^3 + B N^2 + C N + D  \tag{1} $$
and the values of $A,B,C,D$ can be found by imposing that $(1)$ holds for $N=1,2,3,4.$ We get:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}A+B+C+D &=& 1,\\ 8A+4B+2C+D &=& 5,\\ 27A+9B+3C+D&=&14, \\ 64A+16B+4C+D &=& 30.\end{array}\right.\tag{2} $$
Notice that we need *four* equations since the RHS of $(1)$ has four unknown coefficients.

Now $(2)$ can be solved with many techniques, its solution is:
$$ A = \frac{1}{3},\quad B=\frac{1}{2},\quad C=\frac{1}{6},\quad D=0.\tag{3}$$
There is a solution (and only one) for any system like $(2)$ since the Vandermonde matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
One nice way to check this is the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem. Lets
$\ds{\,{\rm S}_{k}\pars{n} \equiv \sum_{i\ =\ 0}^{n}i^{k}}$. Note that, with
$\ds{s = 1,2,3,\ldots}$, 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ {\,{\rm S}_{k}\pars{n} \over n^{s}}
&=
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ {\,{\rm S}_{k}\pars{n + 1} - \,{\rm S}_{k}\pars{n}
 \over \pars{n + 1}^{s} - n^{s}}
=\lim_{N\ \to\ \infty}\ {\pars{n + 1}^{k} \over sn^{s - 1}}
={1 \over s}\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ n^{k - s + 1}
\\[5mm]&=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
0 & \mbox{if} & s > k + 1
\\
{1 \over s} & \mbox{if} & s = k + 1
\\
\infty & \mbox{if} & s < k
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
We see that the highest power of a polynomial must be $\ds{k + 1}$. For instance,
$\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}n^{\dsc{2}}}$ is a polynomial of order $\dsc{2 + 1}=\dsc{3}$.

---

In addittion, the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem is quite helpful in dealing with the polynomial coefficients. We'll evaluate $\ds{A, B, C, D}$ with the present OP example:
$\ds{\,{\cal S}\pars{n}=\sum_{i\ =\ 0}^{n}i^{2}=An^{3} + Bn^{2} + Cn + D}$:
$$
\,{\cal S}\pars{0}=0\quad\imp\quad D = 0\quad\mbox{such that}\quad
\,{\cal S}\pars{n}=\sum_{i\ =\ 0}^{n}i^{2}=An^{3} + Bn^{2} + Cn
$$

> $$
> \mbox{Then,}\quad
> \color{#66f}{\large A}
> =\lim_{n\ \to \infty}{\,{\cal S}\pars{n} \over n^{3}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{ 1\over 3}}\quad\imp\quad
> \,{\cal S}\pars{n} - {1 \over 3}\,n^{3}=Bn^{2} + Cn
> $$

Again,
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large B}&
=\lim_{n\ \to \infty}{\,{\cal S}\pars{n} - n^{3}/3 \over n^{2}} = 
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ {\pars{n + 1}^{2} - \pars{n + 1}^{3}/3 + n^{3}/3
\over 2n + 1} = \color{#66f}{\large\half}
\\[5mm]\imp&
\,{\cal S}\pars{n} - {1 \over 3}\,n^{3} - \half\,n^{2}=Cn
\end{align}

> Finally,
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large C}&
> =\lim_{n\ \to \infty}{\,{\cal S}\pars{n} - n^{3}/3 - n^{2}/2 \over n}
> \\[5mm]&= \lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\
> \bracks{6\pars{n + 1}^{2} - 2\pars{n + 1}^{3} + 2n^{3}
> - 3\pars{n + 1}^{2} + 3n^{2} \over 6}
> = \color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 6}}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{A = {1 \over 3}\,,\ B = \half}$ and $\ds{C = {1 \over 6}}$ we'll get:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\,{\cal S}\pars{n}}
=\sum_{i\ =\ 0}^{n}i^{2}=An^{3} + Bn^{2} + Cn + D
=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 3}\,n^{3} + \half\,n^{2} + {1 \over 6}\,n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

> Why does $~\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2 = An^3+Bn^2+Cn + D$ ?

Why ? Imagine the Egyptians building the pyramids: On top of the pyramid, there is a single brick. Then, on the level directly below that, there are $2\times2=2^2$ bricks. Then, on the level directly below that, there are $3\times3=3^2$ bricks, etc. By the time we get at the base level, there are $n^2$ such bricks. So, how many bricks are there, in total ? Well, the volume of a *smooth* pyramid is the height times the basis over three, so $N\simeq\dfrac{n\cdot n^2}3=\dfrac{n^3}3$. Why only approximately? Because ours has edges, and is not smooth, their presence being responsible for the rest of the terms.